# Simple form collection_radio_buttons show items from record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want to display all the available types in radio buttons in order to click and select on of them

`= f.collection_radio_buttons :type_id, Type.all, :label => "Available Types"`

but I'm getting the following error
`wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 4..6)`

How can I fix the `collection_radio_buttons` in order to get the correct number of arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the api doc on collection_radio_buttons:

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_radio_buttons

it definitely indicates you need at least 4 arguments (minimum):
`method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}`
You have provided 3 - a method `:type_id` a collection `Type.all`
You've also provided options, but have missed the `value_method` and `text_method` That's what you need to add to make this work.

What method will be called on each `Type` for the text/values of the select-options? Usually this is something like: `:id` (for `value_method`) and something like `:name` (for `text_method`)

Comment: Is this same for `simple_form` too ?

Comment: Ya I think so - AFAIK simple form just passes through all standard from-helpers to rails itself, if it doesn't overload them.